# How to declare an optional jQuery dependency with AMD and commonjs

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

How do you declare an optional dependency to jQuery within a pure javascript plugin?

My current plugin starts with:

```
(function (root, factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        // if i put 'jQuery' in the array here that's a forced dependency
        // and I want it optional
        define([], factory);
    }
    else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
        module.exports = factory();
    }
    else {
        root.myPlugin = factory(root.$ || root.jQuery);
    }
}(this, function (jQuery) {

    "use-strict";
     ... plug-in code

}));
```

Comment: Your use of the term "plugin" makes it sound like you are writing a *jQuery* plugin. If that's the case, then jQuery is not optional because a jQuery plugin is usless without jQuery.

Comment: A plugin extends the capabilities of a larger application. It doesn't indicate jQuery, while that is these days the norm.

My code above wants to know if jQuery is available to then add extra functionality - such as storing data within the elements so users can do the norm $(element).data('pluginName'). Without jQuery though, it just returns the data by ids stored on elements. 

Basically, jQuery will extend the plugin - the plugin is not an extension of jQuery.